# Error with bgStretcher - jQuery conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement the bgStretcher jQuery plugin, and seem to get some conflicts. I'm still relatively new to jQuery, and conflicts still puzzle me.

My current site is here - http://65.60.53.10/~purerun/

The bgStretcher is giving the following error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined - but it's within the plugin code.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // other code
   jQuery('body').bgStretcher({images: ['http://65.60.53.10/~purerun/wp-content/gallery/backgrounds/26.jpg','http://65.60.53.10/~purerun/wp-content/gallery/backgrounds/img_4793.jpg'], nextSlideDelay: '10000'});
}
```

Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

The nextSlideDelay value you should be a number not a string; try removing the quotes around it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   // other code
   jQuery('body').bgStretcher({images: ['http://65.60.53.10/~purerun/wp-content/gallery/backgrounds/26.jpg','http://65.60.53.10/~purerun/wp-content/gallery/backgrounds/img_4793.jpg'], nextSlideDelay: 10000});
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: While that's true and I did fix it, the error still occurs and is unrelated to this.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @MetalAdam Does the error persist if you use relative URLs for the images instead of absolute?

Comment: Checked with relative URLs - no change.

Comment: The error appears to be within the plugins' anchoring; it could be that it requires the original image size to be included in the initialization to properly position it. Have you tried adding in the original image size as outlined in the documentation for the plugin?